# why array modifier merging the mesh in each other?

Tags: modifiers

Why array not starting from the edge of the mesh.

[image]

[Blend File](https://pasteall.org/blend/e705f8ffd54a4018a3b4762095ff4af5)

I have empty and making array around the surface. Adding array its merge the mesh in each other.
[image]

How to make the array from the edge to edge. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: does it happen all around or just between first and last? In the latter case it's because it has no clue where it is supposed to stop, to fix this you can for example scale down the ornement until you're good

Comment: @moonboots all around all the mesh.

Comment: oh my bad you're not using a Curve modifier, just an Array with an Object Offset, so I it maybe that your object rotation angle is not enough

Comment: if it's still not that, share your file  ;)

Comment: @moonboots plz check question file attached

Comment: @atek - could you please use blend-exchange to upload files? Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2620/23985), especially the "Sometimes screenshots don't tell the full story", if you want to know why.

Comment: so that's what I said, the empty (which is your Offset Object) rotation angle is too low, so your ornement overlap itself, if you increase the rotation angle it will work, except between first and last. So you need to find a solution. Problem : your ornement is bent...

Answer (score 1):

You have an *Array* modifier with *Object Offset*. The offset object is an empty. Its rotation value is too low, so your ornement overlaps itself. If you increase the rotation value (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) you will avoid overlapping except between first and last.

Your ornement is bent, you should have made sure that it covered 1/4 of a circle (or 1/3 or 1/5 but not 1.2/4, otherwise the overlapping had to happen.

I'm not sure there's any easy solution if you didn't keep a flat version of your ornement. You can try to flatten it back with the *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode (and Z axis). Then try *Array + Curve* or *Array + Simple Deform* modifier to make the ornement go 360° with no overlapping, then modify the ornement a bit so that it sticks to the glass.

[image]

Comment: Can you plz share the file. Let me learn how you have achieved it. Thanks

Comment: select the empty (your offset object) and rotate it 19° on the Z axis. But it will still overlap between last and first instance, so it still doesn't work, you should find another method, actually you can try to flat back your ornement with the Simple Deform modifier / Bend mode, then use another method to duplicate it around like Array + Curve or Array + Simple Deform